# I there any example of custom activity other than REST

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-activity

As per the documentation here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/custom-activity-config.html
These are valid values for type:

- MultiCriteriaDecision
- DataExtensionUpdate
- EMAILV2
- EngagementDecision
- randomSplit
- Wait
- Rest

We did some Rest type custom activities but I am wondering if there's any example of the other types.